# JQuery nao serialize radios input value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, input, radiobutton

Ola,
Tenho um form que é enviado via Ajax, tive que adicionar uns inputs de radio. Porém o metodo `serialize()` nao pega os valores dos radios (tenho dois grupos de radios nesse form), todos os outros inputs dao certo, mais com os radios manda em branco.

Metodo de enviar o form via Ajax:

```
function sendForm(_formID, _url) {
    /* Esse console.log imprime o vlaue de todos os inputs do form, menos do radio selecionado. */
    console.log($('#'+_formID).serialize());  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: _url,
        data: $('#'+_formID).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            alert('success', 4500);
            clearAllInputs(_formID);
            refreshList(area+'List.php');
            console.log('sendForm');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('error', 4500);
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

HTML de um dos grupos dos radios:

```
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radioPaymentType" id="radioMoney" value="money" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="radioMoney">Dinheiro</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radioPaymentType" id="radioCheck" value="check">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="radioCheck">Cheque</label>
   </div>
```

Forma que recebo no PHP:

```
$paymentType = $_POST['radioPaymentType'];
```

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou normal. O console mostra no serialize: `radioPaymentType=money`. Inclusive o PHP retorna `money`.

Comment: @Sam Estranho, aqui nao exibe os valores dos radios. Olha o console.log()  do serialize():
`code=&title=Almofada%20e%20ilumina%C3%A7ao%20do%20headset%20com%20problema%20&status=Pendente&client=359&vehicle=117&price=1%2C23&radioPaymentType=&radioPaymentStatus=&dateRegister=2019-06-30&dateExpectedCompleted=&dateCompleted=&detail=123`